# How to read custom fields (not XMP metadata) from PDF using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

Is there other method then buying `iTextSharp` or `Aspose`?

Comment: You do not need to buy iTextSharp, it is available licensed with AGPL, too, after all. If that contradicts your requirements, please complete your question to include all relevant requirements. That being said, which custom fields do you mean? Do you mean "custom metadata in the document information dictionary" according to section 14.3.3 of [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)?

Comment: People promoting AGPL/GPL software as 'free' are usually promoting their own agandas. Lets be straight... unless you are developing GPL software in the first place, GPL is not free.

Answer (score 0):

You could buy [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) instead.

The library can be used to read field values or to export form data as FDF file.

Here are samples that might be relevant for your task:

- [Read combo box items](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Forms%20and%20Annotations/ReadComboBoxItems)
- [Find control by name](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Forms%20and%20Annotations/FindControlByName)
- [Export FDF data](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Forms%20and%20Annotations/ExportFdfData)
- [Fill existing form](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Forms%20and%20Annotations/FillForm)

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.